# Handling orientation for framework in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiinterfaceorientation

Is it possible to allow both orientations for third party framework? Suppose I am using "XYZ" third party framework in my app. I don't have access to its source code. This framework needs landscape orientation to be allowed by application for some functionality. But my application only supports portrait mode. So I want allow landscape mode only to "XYZ" framework. Is there any way to do this?

As per my understanding, to solve this problem we can allow both orientations to app and in each viewcontroller we can block landscape orientation.But I don't think this is good solution if application is having 20-30 view controllers.

Answer (score 1):

In order for some of your view controllers to support multiple orientations, theses orientation should be allowed for the entire app. That means that the solution you described is the way to go (limiting the orientation changes on most of the view controllers in the app). However, you don't have to add manual treatment to each view controller. You can subclass UIViewController, add treatment for only supporting a single orientation even though the containing app supports multiple orientations, and have all of your other view controllers inherit from this new UIViewController subclass instead of directly from UIViewController.

I hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: @Chonach, thanks for your response. I thought of same...but in this case in future I need to take care of inheriting each class from base class. Also in current situation I have to go each file and need to make it subclass of new base class. I am looking if there is any other better solution. :)

Comment: Good luck with that, and please let us know if you find one, but as far as I know, there isn't one... :-/ I've had some experience with a similar scenario to the one you're describing and dealing with multiple orientation, when only specific parts of the app support it, is a big headache. You shouldn't try all kinds of hacks that may end up working on not working. Go with the safest route, it will save you time in the long run...